# How can i control error status in React router loader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `react router dom 6.22.3`

I have created `browser router` like this

```
{
    path: "/",
    element: <MainLayout />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Dashboard />,
        loader: DashbaordLoader,
        errorElement: <Error />,
      },
    ]
}
```

Inside the `Dashboard` Component I am fetching data.

```
export const DashbaordLoader = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await fetcher("http://localhost:3000/users", "GET");
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The `fetcher` is just the `javascript` fetch function

```
export const fetcher = async (url: string, method: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method, 
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "",
      },
    });
    return response.json()
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

As you can see there is no `Authorization` token so the server is responding like this

With status code `401`

In the body `{error: 'Need to login'}`

But the thing is in the `dashboardLoader`. even though the data is with `statusCode 401`

It doesn't goes into the `catch block`. How can i make it show the error element when the response is `401`

Here is the error response in `postman`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your fetcher caught and "handled" the error, and then is simply returning it. The loader sees this as just a normal return value.

Re-throw the error so the loader can "catch and handle" it.

```js
export const fetcher = async (url: string, method: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method, 
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "",
      },
    });
    return response.json();
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error, log it, analytics, etc???

    // re-throw error for downstream handlers
    throw err;
  }
};
```

You will likely want to do the same in your loader as well, so errors can be thrown and returned to the UI *as errors*.

```js
export const DashbaordLoader = async () => {
  try {
    return fetcher("http://localhost:3000/users", "GET");
  } catch (err) {
    // handle any logging/etc, and re-throw error
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Comment: I throw err like your code But the thing is inside the `fetcher` function the await response doesn't goes into catch block. Its goes into the response.json() instead

Comment: That's weird, a 401 should go into the `catch` block.

Comment: I show the postman response in the picture

Comment: @KhantMinSiThu `fetch` only rejects on network errors and CORS issues (and cancelled requests). See [Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful). I guess you can explicitly check for the 401 status in the  `fetcher` and manually throw the error, or implement some other way to indicate the request/response is not ok.